# Commands handled by git-shell on prompt don't do anything (just hangs)

Tags: c, git, ssh

I'm trying to set up a git repository on my remote linux server such that I can connect via ssh and share the single login with a few friends in a fairly secure way. I'm running into issues because my sshd calls duo security via `FORCE_COMMAND` set in the ssh config (points to `'/usr/sbin/login_duo'`). I decided to work around this; so I checked out the git code and picked up enough C to make the changes (in [shell.c](http://code.google.com/p/git-core/source/browse/shell.c%20shell.c)) so that it ignores the /usr/sbin/login_duo call and calls `run_shell()` that creates the normal git-shell prompt. (I'm now pretty sure this is not the right solution because I wouldn't expect a `git clone` call to end up in a shell, but this question still seems valid)

Anyway, I managed to get the `git>` prompt to appear but it doesn't seem to process the input I pass in (Once I've typed enter/exit and then hit return). I would expect it to print "git got x" but it just sits there. Any ideas?

```
            fprintf(stderr, "git> ");
            if (strbuf_getline(&line, stdin, '\n') == EOF) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "\n");
                    strbuf_release(&line);
                    break;
            }
            fprintf(stderr, "git got %s\n", line );
```

Example:

```
egwor@mars:~/projects/test$ git clone ssh://git@localhost/home/git/repo1
Cloning into repo1...
git@localhost's password: 
login_duo ignored <-- where I split off and call the shell function
git> exit
<--hangs-->`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`line` is of type:

```
struct strbuf {
    size_t alloc;
    size_t len;
    char *buf;
};
```

`fprintf(stderr, "git got %s\n", line )` should generate a compiler warning along the lines of:

 `warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’...`

Ignoring this warning and running the code is likely to cause a seg-fault or other bad-crumble.

Try this instead:

```
fprintf(stderr, "git got %s\n", line.buf );
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks! That must have been it; I had expected that it would have just given me a memory location at worst. I must have just missed the warning [I always get an error when it tries to build the tcl code, so must have unfortunately just missed it].

Comment: the results are undefined & depend upon the values of `alloc` & `len`. for example, if `alloc`is zero you won't get much out but it won't fall over ;)